# stacking swf files on top of each other

Tags: html, css, flash

is it possible to load multiple swf files directly on top of each other? I feel like I'm close using divs with different z-indexing, but what about the flash player? Am I wrong in thinking that for each swf there is an individual flash player associated with it? And if that is true, can they be stacked directly on top of each other(on the z-axis)?

thanks for clearing this up for me. I don't want to beat my head against the wall if it is structurally impossible.

to clarify this: you would only be able to see the top swf, but if it were removed, say with swfobject.removeSWF(), there would be another one in the exact same location, but with a lower Z-index

Comment: Show us an example of your markup on [dabblet.com](http://dabblet.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure it's possible. See this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ezXjx/)**.

**HTML**

```
<div id="a">
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://edmullen.net/flash/relog.swf" width="200" height="200">
        <param name="movie" value="http://edmullen.net/flash/relog.swf" />
        <param name="WMode" value="Transparent" />
    </object>
</div>
<div id="b">
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://edmullen.net/flash/relog.swf" width="200" height="200">
        <param name="movie" value="http://edmullen.net/flash/relog.swf" />
        <param name="WMode" value="Transparent" />
    </object>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#a {
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   z-index:10;
}
#b {
   position:absolute;
   top:100px;
   left:100px;
   z-index:20;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean same location? The second movie partially overlaps the first one.

Comment: Sure, you can see that in the demo if you play with the top and left position of the styling.

Comment: No, you don't need to login to see or use jsfiddle. What are you trying to do with the fiddle?

Comment: I can't see what you change to the fiddle unless you update it and insert the new URL.

Comment: got it. Thanks so much for your help! I was making it harder that it was.